# Flyway 3.0 to 4.0 upgrade fails (at least for Postgres)

Tags: database-migration, flyway

We tried to go directly from Flyway 3.0 to 4.0 to get access to Repeatable Migrations. (Thus skipping versions 3.1 and 3.2.)

The SQL run via `MetaDataTableImpl.upgradeIfNecessary` drops the indexes `schema_version_vr_idx` and `schema_version_ir_idx` which did not exist in version 3.0's schema, so Postgres is not happy.

A way to support serveral version upgrade could be to use `DROP INDEX IF EXISTS schema_version_vr_idx;`, but that needs to be adopted to the different databases of course.

For now I solved the problem by creating these two indexes before running Flyway to upgrade the schema.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually those indexes did exists by default: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/flyway-3.0/flyway-core/src/main/resources/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/postgresql/createMetaDataTable.sql

No idea why or how they were removed on your DB instance.

Comment: Fair enough. Our migrations table must have been created from outside Flyway than.